# How should one handle newlines in bbcode?

Tags: css, whitespace, bbcode, pecl, nl2br

I'm using the PECL bbcode extension to define a set of tags which I allow for a forum. I have implemented pretty much all of the tags described at http://www.bbcode.org.

Forum users have come to expect that when they take a new line in the input field, their post will take a new line as well. I'm trying to make this happen.

#### The `nl2br()` way

`nl2br()` is great for making the browser take newlines when the user types them, as it finds newlines and throws `<br />` tags in there to make the browser take a newline as well. But this throws a wrench in some of the more complex markup.

For example:

```
[ul]
[li]list item 1[/li]
[li]list item 2[/li]
[/ul]
```

results in

```
<ul><br />
<li>list item 1</li><br />
<li>list item 2</li><br />
<ul>
```

which throws whitespace everywhichwhere. Tables have similar issues for the same reason. In addition, any tag which actually displays whitespace (e.g. `<pre><code>code goes here</code></pre>`) gets double-spaced. Icky.

#### The CSS way

CSS has `white-space` rules which can come in handy in these situations. If we put all forum posts inside a `.bbcode` element and then just include the stylesheet rule

```
.bbcode {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

then the browser will preserve newlines, collapse other whitespace, and wrap words. This sounds pretty ideal. However, list items etc. still get this double-spacing issue because the browser displays the newline after each `</li>`.

We can get around *some* of this by defining:

```
.bbcode {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
.bbcode * {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

which alleviates the issue in lists and tables. However, now newlines only appear in the root element of the post, so taking a newline in e.g. a table-cell doesn't work.

#### The how-do-I-do-this? way

Really what I would like would be the combination of two effects:

- the browser takes a newline when the source takes a newline outside of all tags
- the browser takes a newline when the source takes a newline *not immediately after the closing or opening of block-level or structural tags*

Ideally speaking, I think `[li]some\ntext[/li]` should result in two lines, `[li]sometext[/li]\n` should only result in one line, and `[i]sometext[/i]\n` should result in two lines.

How is something like this done? Or rather, what do people typically do in forums that use bbcode? I could probably write a function in which I define all the cases in which a `<br />` should be inserted, this smells strongly of re-inventing many wheels.

Answer (score 1):

What I've settled on now is the

#### The `nl2br-str_replace` Way

```
$html = nl2br(bbcode_parse($handler, htmlentities($bbcode_string)));
$html = str_replace(
    array('</div><br />', '<tr><br />', '</tr><br />', '<th><br />', '</th><br />', '<td><br />', '</td><br />', '<ul><br />', '</ul><br />', '<ol><br />', '</ol><br />', '<li><br />', '</li><br />', '</pre><br />'),
    array('</div>', '<tr>', '</tr>', '<th>', '</th>', '<td>', '</td>', '<ul>', '</ul>', '<ol>', '</ol>', '<li>', '</li>', '</pre>'), $html);
return $html;
```

And CSS:

```
.bbcode pre br {
    display: none;
}
```

What's going on here? Rather than defining where I *want* newlines, I'm defining where I know they'll be and I *don't* want them.

The CSS prevents double-spacing in `pre` elements (and you'll need to add any other elements which take newlines from whitespace). The PHP gets rid of newlines caused by the user putting newlines between e.g. `[li]stuff[/li]` elements.

This is brittle: if the user types a space after the [/li] and before the newline, the `<br />` doesn't get removed. I could probably use regular expressions to look for `[tag][whitespace]<br />` but I don't see that as a huge issue.

---

I'm accepting this answer for now as it's the best that I've been able to come up with or find over the last couple days. If somebody else knows of a better solution, please post it and I'll be happy to accept it instead.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody else has a solution, I would love to hear and accept it, but in the interim the best solution I've been able to come up with is what I will term:

#### The Sneaky (but invalid HTML) CSS Way

Just use PHP's `nl2br()` function, keep the the `white-space: normal`, but add the following CSS rules:

```
.bbcode ul > br,
.bbcode ol > br,
.bbcode table > br,
.bbcode tr > br,
.bbcode pre br {
    display: none;
}
```

Basically, this lets you define instances of "br" which should not be displayed. In particular, I'm hiding them when they're in a list but not a list item, in a table but not in a cell, and in a pre (where whitespace is already preserved).

We then need to hide trailing linebreaks from block-level elements:

```
.bbcode table + br,
.bbcode ul + br,
.bbcode ol + br,
.bbcode div + br,
.bbcode iframe + br,
.bbcode pre + br,
.bbcode blockquote + br {
    display: none;
}
```

And that's about it! We could make to with a single rule with a lot of `elem + br` rules, but as I have never heard of this kind of selector before I'm playing it safe where I can by using selector notation that I know to be (fairly) cross-browser compatible where I can.

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: Having `br` simply not display doesn’t make the invalid markup they create when inside a list or a table one bit better. That’s not “sneaky”, it is just fighting symptoms instead of what is really wrong.

Comment: Good point, I've adjusted the title. I am still hoping to hear of a better way, but until then this is what I'll be running with.

Comment: Another note: this does *not* cleanly remove linebreaks from between table elements, as browsers (well, at least chrome) will "fix" the bad markup by moving the `<br>` tags to before the table before the stylesheet has a chance to hide them.